# Documentação em XML

Tags: php, xml, visual-studio, documentação

Desenvolvo um framework em PHP e não gostaria de comentar o código do framework direto nas classes, por diversas razões.

Então gostaria de saber se existe algum editor que faz a leitura da documentação a partir de um XML ou algo parecido, por exemplo:

- **Repository.php** - classe utilizada sem documentação
- **Repository.php.xml** - classe documentada ou apenas informações de documentação.

No Visual Studio essa funcionalidade é utilizada com os scripts:

- **jquery.js** - scripts sem documentação
- **jquery.vsdoc.js** - scripts com documentação

Comment: não conheço, mais é uma ótima pergunta

Comment: Vou postar no Stackoverflow em inglês para aumentar o range dessa questão!

Comment: posta o link da questão no stack em inglês pra gente poder acompanhar junto

Comment: Sem resposta até o momento. Estou fazendo pesquisa com alguns conhecidos da área também. Aparentemente o Komodo IDE tem suporte para intellisense como jquery e frameworks PHP através de um XML. Mais tarde vou procurar o arquivo xml e ver como funciona esse modelo!

Comment: Assim que tiver resposta eu atualizo esse tópico caso alguém um dia pesquise a mesma coisa!

Comment: certo, de qualuqer forma a pergunta talvez seja algo a ser criado, tai uma boa alternativa de documentação, q não "polui" o código.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049861/autocomplete-syntax-for-html-or-php-in-notepad-not-auto-close-autocompelete

Comment: O que isso tem a ver Guilherme? aehaehauehaue

Comment: Não tenho permissão pra comentar ainda, então vou me arriscar dar uma sugestão aqui: Você não pode comentar as suas classes normalmente, rodar o PHPDoc pra gerar a documentação, e depois rodar um script que remova todos os comentários do código? Fazer o script não seria difícil e você pode incluir ele no processo de deploy se tiver utilizando alguma ferramenta do tipo.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: A solução do @NewtonWagner me parece a mais plausível sem reinventar a roda.

Comment: Sim é uma ótima ideia, não gosto de comentários no código, portanto manter esses comentários em classe está fora de questão, se a documentação ficar separada me agrada e posso ter uma documentação completa e em caso de errata ou novas funcionalidades posso alterar a documentação sem precisar  mexer nas classes que vão ser utilizados pelos demais desenvolvedores e não por mim que conheço o sistema de cabo a rabo cada linha... Moderação como eu faço? Acredito que não exista resposta pra isso no atual momento... a única que encontrei foi uma IDE que permite usar arquivos customizados para DOC

Comment: Parece que o PHP Tools for Visual Studio pode ajudar https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe alguns modos de gerar a documentação do php, mas a maioria desses API's geram a documentação a partir de análises do seu código. Vou deixar alguns links aqui:

- [phpdocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)
- [apigen](http://apigen.org/##installation)
- [phpdox](http://phpdox.de/demo.html)
- [phpdoc](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-php-documentation-comments.html) - Neste caso ele gera a partir de blocos de comentário

Existe uma questão no StackOverflow em inglês também que pode ter a resposta para a sua pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598903/automatic-php-documentation-generator), mas eu acredito que, pelo menos atualmente, não haja nenhuma ferramenta ou plugin de terceiros que faça a documentação via XML (o que, na minha opinião é muito mais fácil).

Comment: Sim, acredito que hoje não exista! O fato é que a documentação separada permite classes mais limpas e com quantidade de linhas significativas a menos e a facilidade da manutenção de todas as páginas da documentação. O que precisava é gerar uma documentação inicial a partir do código e complementar o textual nessa documentação gerada!

Comment: Neste caso acredito que você possa usar o PHPDoc pelo comentário de código e pegar as documentações que ele gera pelo fonte dele para alterar, falando é fácil rs mas não sei se ele permite a edição assim tão aberta